# Google Import Offline Conversions set Username and Password

Tags: import, passwords, offline, google-ads-api

In ADS account you can schedule offline conversions via HTTPS.

Since is an public URL I want to set the Username and Password before I deliver the .csv or .xls.

I can't find any documentation on how google is sending the Username or Password to the given URL.
It is not with POST.

Thank you

[screen from ads account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSzbt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems is basic HTTP auth.
In PHP you can check using $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'].
Hope it will help others.